# How do you section a list of points within the same area?

Tags: c#, plot, partitioning

[image: 1]

This is the representation of all the points I have and I need to **partition them into equal sections**. I plotted the list of points using GNUPlot but what I want is the 'area selection/partition'.

Like this:

[image]

How do you suppose I do that? I haven't performed a deep research on it and tried coding but I'd like to output a file that contains the grouped points, that when I separately plot them in GNUPlot, it will display the 'section/partition', either the **1**, **2**, or **3**. You can point me the right way so I can try on C#.

The [List of points](https://shrib.com/#Woodchuck73YyVky)

Comment: _partition them into equal sections_ please define 'equal'..: number of points? area enclosed? or what?

Comment: @TaW Horizontally equal, just like the 2nd Image on my question. With that said, the number of points in a certain section should also be equal with the others.

Comment: @TaW, I tried sorting the points from smallest to largest and then divided them into 3 equal number of points, when I plotted them in GNUPlot, it was vertically divided. Close, but what I really need is to divide them horizontally equal.